# How to add List of comments in Rally java rest API

Tags: java, rest, rally

I have found that if we pass the definition ConversationPosts it will create the comments in Discussion tab. But how to add a list of Conversations to the discussion in Rally Java rest API

```
JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
newDefect.addProperty("Type", "ConversationPost");
newDefect.addProperty("Text", "Test Comment 2");
newDefect.addProperty("Artifact",defectReference);
newDefect.addProperty("User", userRef);
CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("ConversationPost", defectObject);
CreateResponse createResponse = rallyRestAPI.create(createRequest);
```

If we need to add 2 comments say "Test Comment 1" ,"Test Comment 2" to the same defect how this can be done in a single execution

Comment: How do we know what this is about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Rally's WSAPI doesn't have any batch create/update endpoints so you'll just have to create your conversation post items one at a time.  Your code above looks good.

```
String[] comments = {"Test Comment 1", "Test Comment 2"};
for(String comment : comments) {
    JsonObject newDefect = new JsonObject();
    newDefect.addProperty("Type", "ConversationPost");
    newDefect.addProperty("Text", comment);
    newDefect.addProperty("Artifact",defectReference);
    newDefect.addProperty("User", userRef);
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("ConversationPost", defectObject);
    CreateResponse createResponse = rallyRestAPI.create(createRequest);
}
```